# How to unit test var variables

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, var

I test Angular application. This fact should not be of high importance here though.
My function to be tested looks like this:

```
    $scope.showItem = function (item) {
        if (item.selected) {
            activeItems.push(item);
        } else {
            var index = _.indexOf(activeItems, items);
            activeItems.splice(index, 1);
        }
    };
```

Function works as desired. Array activeItems is used in another function which after some modifications assigns the result to the scope.
The behavior is that if the item is not selected it is added to the array. If the item is already selected, it will be removed from the array.

```
    it('should remove an item from the array', function () {
        var activeItems = [{id: 1, selected: false}, {id:2, selected: true}];
        var item = {
            id: 1,
            selected: false
        };
        expect(activeItems.length).toEqual(2);
        scope.showItem(item);
        expect(activeItems.length).toEqual(1); // FAIL!
        // expects do not work for var variables. would work, if activeItems is assigned to the scope
    });
```

If I assign activeItems to the scope (scope.activeItems instead of var activeItems), it all works; however,  I believe that if the variable is not to be shown in the view, it should not be assigned to the scope.

First expect will work because is defined inside it block:

```
expect(activeItems.length).toEqual(2);
```

Second will not:

```
expect(activeItems.length).toEqual(1);
```

but it would for scope variable:

```
expect(scope.activeItems.length).toEqual(1);
```

My question is how to test that var value?

Comment: It sounds to me like you're trying to test the internal implementation of your method.  Take a step back, think about what your function is trying to achieve from a business/functional perspective and write your tests according to that.

Comment: Also, `activeItems` is a property of your `$scope` in your current implementation of `showItem`, so in order for you to test that it actually does something is to add it to the scope otherwise it's just a global variable. Secondly, `activeItems` must be assigned since you use it in both cases of selection.

Comment: Thanks for your comments (including @wyattbergeron1 below).
I was told once not to attach to the $scope variables which will not be displayed in the view. That's why activeItems is a global var instead of $scope.activeItems. 
Later on in the code activeItems is used to build another $scope array, which is tested correctly.
Your answers did help to undestand what needs to be tested.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive, as it's hard to tell your intentions, and if you have any other globals, but I think your error is that your using `activeItems` outside of it's scope., but again its hard to tell because you may have other globals causing the problem. If it is that `activeItems` is outside of it's scope, then `it` will reach an error at `expect`,`scope`, and`expect` again. Then it won't effect the array, and it will stay as it was edited during `showItem`

Hope this helps!